# Delayed job queue limit. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, threadpool, delayed-job

I want to limit the number of concurrent processess working at the same time in [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem  for a concrete queue name, in order to simulate a Thread Pool pattern.

My code looks like this:

```
MyProcessor.new.delay(:queue => "myQueue").perform()
```

I'm trying with priorities but i can't get it:

```
MyProcessor.new.delay(:queue => "myQueue", :priority => incremental_priority).perform()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just start the desired number of delayed job workers?

Comment: Because I don't know the number before starting them. The workers do imagen processing in background and the images number is different each request because of the user selection. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I don't think you can do that - short of starting/stopping worker processes on demand